# Use Maven to aggregate projects

Tags: maven, build

I am **not** asking about parent pom etc. I have one or more common kind of projects.. let's call them C1, C2, ... .
I have some projects with use these common projects. Let's call them P1, P2, ...
These projects P... have common maven dependencies. I want to extract it into a separate pom rather than repeat it.
I am not interested in parent pom solution. IMO parent pom is when you run a single build in parent, and it builds all children which are related.. e.g. a war, a common jar, a rest jar, a data access jar, a buss logic jar etc.
My projects P... are independent of each other. So I want to **refer** to a common pom. How to do? Thanks.

Comment: Extract the common dependencies into a single pom where you use dependencyManagement than you can use this so called BOM (Bill Of Materials) and make an import in your other projects...so you have a defined list of dependencies. But you can also achieve this by using a common parent which is not related to a multi module build.

Answer (score 1):

Extract your P... projects common dependencies into another Maven project. Then add this new project into your  of your P... projects with type pom and scope import.

Comment: hmm Didier that is ok but there is no clear or proper example available.. how about putting it on github and writing an article?